# How to resolve an invalid shape for monophonic audio

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, audio-processing, librosa

I've loaded a model for testing on Jupyter Notebook and created a path for the wav audio file I plan on testing:

```
anger = "C:\\Desktop\\Emotion Speech Recognition\\D_10\\10ANG_XX.wav"
```

However after I've extracted the features from another Python file, I seem to be getting this error and I'm not quite sure if i'm reading the audio path correctly or If there needs to be a conversion.
Please see below. Any advise or explanation would help!

P.S This is my first time doing audio processing. :)

```
ParameterError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d282e0102c33> in <module>
      1 # extract features and reshape it
----> 2 features = extract_feature(anger, mfcc=True, chroma=True, mel=True).reshape(1, -1)

~\Desktop\Emotion Speech Recognition\Emotion_Speech_Recognizer.py in extract_feature(file_name, **kwargs)
     52 
     53         if chroma or contrast:
---> 54             stft = np.abs(librosa.stft(floaty_num))
     55             new_audio_result = np.array([])
     56         if mfcc:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\spectrum.py in stft(y, n_fft, hop_length, win_length, window, center, dtype, pad_mode)
    213 
    214     # Check audio is valid
--> 215     util.valid_audio(y)
    216 
    217     # Pad the time series so that frames are centered

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\util\utils.py in valid_audio(y, mono)
    266     if mono and y.ndim != 1:
    267         raise ParameterError('Invalid shape for monophonic audio: '
--> 268                              'ndim={:d}, shape={}'.format(y.ndim, y.shape))
    269 
    270     elif y.ndim > 2 or y.ndim == 0:

ParameterError: Invalid shape for monophonic audio: ndim=2, shape=(96768, 2)
```

Comment: Please include the traceback as text rather than an image

Comment: you need to provide the code where you are loading the file, up until where the error occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just found the solution to my own problem. The .wave file I was using was stereo. So, I ended up converting it to mono using " from pydub import AudioSegment" and setting it to only 1 channel. :)

Comment: One can do also do like this.                                   
            sound_mono1 = audio_signal[1:len(audio_signal),0 ]
sound_mono2 = audio_signal[1:len(audio_signal),1 ]